# Modify content of a CSV file in Golang

Tags: csv, go

My problem is that I have a csv file with a content. Like:

```
Number,Name
1,First
2,Second
3,Third
```

In this table I want to change one of the value with golang. For example obtain this content:

```
Number,Name
1,First
2,Change
3,Third
```

The only thing I found is to add value in the csv file and not change it.
How implemement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the csv, transform the data, write it back. Cannot be done inplace.

Comment: Normally, modifying a text file in place is considered difficult because the text being substituted may not be the same size as the original.  In your example, Second and Change are both six bytes long.  Probably a happy coincidence.  You probably want to read all the data in and then write it all out again.  If you're sure you want to modify the file in place, you could try using syscall.Mmap() but I've only used it for reading files and it might not be available for all platforms - and it doesn't seem  appropriate for the average CSV file.

Comment: One optimization is to only write back modified data and everything after it. For example, if you have a large file but are only modifying the 2nd to last entry: you would (1) read the last two entries, (2) modify the first of the two, then (3) write those two entries back to the file, starting at the offset of the old entry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this informations! So csv is not efficient for my program I will use another form of data, like xml, json or sql.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient program I can write to modify the sample CSV, named input.csv, would look something like:

```golang
func main() {
    fIn, err := os.Open("input.csv")
    must(err)
    defer fIn.Close()
    fOut, err := os.Create("output.csv")
    must(err)
    defer fOut.Close()

    r := csv.NewReader(fIn)
    w := csv.NewWriter(fOut)

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        must(err)

        if i == 2 {
            record[1] = "Change"
        }

        w.Write(record)
    }

    w.Flush()
    must(w.Error())
}

func must(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

OP never stated how they wanted to identify the record(s) to change.  Above, I chose to change the third record (after the header, and the first row), but other predicates work, too:

```golang
if record[0] == "2" {
    record[1] = "Change"
}
```

or:

```golang
if record[1] == "Second" {
    record[1] = "Change"
}
```